# Can we have Build Automatically option for ANT Build Scripts?

Tags: ant, eclipse-3.4

Eclipse IDE (3.4) contains an option to build the code automatically in the following tab
Project ---> Build Automatically.
When we select this option , we need not build the project manually. It happens Automatically.

Actually I see this working for builtin eclipse build tool. Is there any possibility that ,  we can make it to (Build Automatically) work for seperate ANT build scripts ?

Answer (score 1):

If you add that ant script builder in the builders of your Java project, it will be executed at the same time than the default Java Builder, automatically if the "Build automatically" option is set.

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/5218/eclipseantbuilder.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/5218/eclipseantbuilder.png)